# HTML não encontra imagem <img>

Tags: css, html5, aplicação-web

Boa noite, eu estou tendo um problema com a tag  do HTML,comecei um projeto de um site de um loja virtual, primeiro fiz um rascunho HTML, então quando fui para a parte de PHP, instalei o ambiente WAMP e etc, ao jogar meus templates para a pasta 'www' do wamp eu tive um problema em uma das páginas, algumas imagens pararam de ser reconhecidas pelo template, sendo que estão no mesmo diretório, o caminho está correto, porém só uma imagem está funcionando, segue um trecho do código a baixo:

```
<div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-third w3-container w3-margin-bottom">
      <img src="../imgs/img2.png" alt="Norway" style="width:100%" class="w3-hover-opacity containerimg">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b></p>
        <p>Praesent tincidunt sed tellus ut rutrum. Sed vitae justo condimentum, porta lectus vitae, ultricies congue gravida diam non fringilla.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-container w3-margin-bottom">
      <img src="../imgs/img4.png" alt="Norway" style="width:100%" class="w3-hover-opacity containerimg">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b></p>
        <p>Praesent tincidunt sed tellus ut rutrum. Sed vitae justo condimentum, porta lectus vitae, ultricies congue gravida diam non fringilla.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-container">
      <img src="../imgs/i.png" alt="Norway" style="width:100%" class="w3-hover-opacity containerimg">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b></p>
        <p>Praesent tincidunt sed tellus ut rutrum. Sed vitae justo condimentum, porta lectus vitae, ultricies congue gravida diam non fringilla.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

as imagens "img4.png" e "i.png" não estão sendo mais reconhecidas, porém nos arquivos fora do diretório do wamp, que são exatamente a mesma coisa, ainda funciona. Não é algo muito importante, eu deixei todos com a imagem que 'funciona' já que no momento é só para rascunho, para eu ter uma ideia de como a página irá ficar, mas fiquei curioso,e caso vier acontecer mais adiante.

Grato desde já!

Comment: Com a imagem que não carrega qual é o erro que aparece no Console do DevTools? Testou usar alguma imagem nova? Pega alguma imagem qq na net e testa para ver se carrega

Comment: Imagens que estão na nuvem funcionam, porém acabei de fazer o seguinte, linkei uma imagem da nuvem, funcionou, baixei a mesma imagem, setei o path e já não funcionou mais...Como eu acesso o console?

Comment: Aperta F12 e clica aqui para ver o erro na Aba console http://prntscr.com/muvp1n talvez possa ser uma configuração do WAMP, de não permitir esse tipo de MIME Type, algo que acho muito pouco provável... Então veja o erro que aparece e fala ai, mas muito provavelmente é erro no caminha da imagem

Comment: Obrigado pela dica,amigo! Mas no caminho da imagem não é, sendo que o imagem que está funcionando corretamente esta na mesma pasta, mesmo formato, eu só estou mudando o nome entre a última barra e o ".png", o console acusou not found, http://prntscr.com/muvu9d MIME Type, não sei o que é mas já vou googlar aqui para conferir se pode ser isso, obrigado!

Comment: A mensagem é clara, a imagem não foi encontrada, cara o link pode esta certo, mas pelo que eu percebi vc acessa as img por ../imagem se vc sair do diretorio e incluir no outro arquivo esse codigo e ele estiver em diretorio de camada supeior ou inferior ele não vai encontrar a imagem e vai dar notfound, sempre que eu trabalho com imagem eu uso uma constante que eu defino nos projetos chamado RAIZ, sempre que vou incluir uma imagem uso a raiz e nunca da problema, nao importa onde o arquivo esteja ele vai encontrar